# .NET Core Console Application inside Docker Container - System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)

Tags: c#, docker, curl, console-application

I am experiencing an issue with .Net core console application (ConsoleApp1) which runs on docker container. I have multiple DotNetcore containers setup for ConsoleApp1. Each container I am passing environment variables along with one unique URLs.

I've decided to write a test case to test why some of the URLs not working

The issue I am having is some of the containers are able to call the client but other containers complaining with the error as:

```
ex = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.CurlException: Couldn't connect to server
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAge
```

**Here's the Code I am using:**

```
public static async Task TestIfGivenURLPassORFail()
{
string _baseUrl = "https://abc.domain.dns.com";
//string _baseUrl = "https://def.domain.dns.com";
//string _baseUrl = "https://xyz.domain.dns.com";
string _username = "username";
string _password = "password";
string _extendedPath = "/xml/hoststatus?hostname=domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com";
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_username, _password);
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
//using (handler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true })
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
try
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseUrl);
//client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
//Convert to XML
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_extendedPath);
string stringData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(stringData);
if (stringData != null)
{
    Assert.True(true, "Test pass");
}
else
{
    Assert.True(false, "Test Fail");
}
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred while sending the request.  Response failed for {ex.StackTrace}.");
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you look at the error message you got? It clearly states "_Couldn't connect to server_". Now, why the connection to the server failed is for you to find out (is it with your program? Is it an incorrect URL? Is it something with the certificate or certificate validation? Is it your network settings? Is it something with the server itself?...)

Comment: @elgonzo thanks for your reply, all the servers have setup in the same way and code working fine with the other servers.

Comment: Now, i can only work with what you say here, and i cannot validate the veracity of your arguments. You say all servers are set up the same way. Since your code works with only some of those servers, it cannot be your code (if your code was the problem, it would work with no server, since all servers are set up the same way). It cannot be the server configuration (again, as you say, all servers have the same setup, thus your code should not only work with some but with all of them). (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Taking your argument at face value, the most likely origin of your problem is somewhere with your network, and thus i would suggest you troubleshoot your network configuration and all devices involved (see if you can establish a connection in another way or ping to the problematic server successfully, check the configuration of your client machines, server machines, any routers, firewalls, smart switches, etc...)

Comment: @elgonzo appreciate your input, I connect through VPN remotely to company network and we have firewall. internal server names of the new servers aren't included as aliases on the cert due to new policy but the ones working were grandfathered in.   Researching..